# How to disable parsing of query parameter in http request in aws api gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-api-gateway

I have a rest api generated from cloudformation template. This rest method takes one query parameter "query" as input. This parameter holds graphql query so req uri look like this:

/ScheduleResource?query={getInfoByFoo(foo:"bar")}

If i test it on sam local it works but when I deploy it to api gateway this api returns status 400 with empty body.

It looks like this problem https://nicholasjackson.io/2016/12/13/using-graphql-with-aws-lambda/ that in integration request stage of http call api gateway is trying to parse the query as json and fails (of course), but im afraid that solution works only on POST methods with body.

How can I solve this and pass query to lambda fcn as string parameter?

This is my cloudformation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Outputs the time
Resources:
  ScheduleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: dist/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ./
      Events:
        MyTimeApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /ScheduleResource
            Method: GET
```

Comment: Whats the exact 400 response you see? Can you add that here.